# Label for password field

Tags: jquery, input, passwords, label, field

```
<input type="text" value="useraname" />
<input type="password" value="password" />
```

I'm using jQuery to make the inline labels disappear on click/focus. Password shows bulls as usual, but I wonder if its possible somehow to show "Password" label as text (instead of ••••) inside the password field?

Edited to add: I want the user-typed password to be hidden ofcourse!.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are plugins for that. See [labelify](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/labelify/) for example

Comment: Unless I am mistaken the plugin docs dont mention a password.  I just quickly changed one of the field types to 'password' and all the characters turned the the dots.  Does this plug in work with password fields as the OP requested?

Comment: Same story here. Its only for text fields, not for password fields.

Answer (score 4):

why all that long script for? that jus a simple task which can be done with a half line of code :

```
<input type='text' onclick="this.type='password',value=''" class='watever' value='password'..etc
```

cheers

Comment: Love this, but i think `onfocus` is better than `onclick` because it also triggers when users tab into the field...

Answer (score 2):

Check In-Field Labels jQuery Plugin
http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the code below. Just append `addPassClear("Password")` to any input element that you want this functionality for.

```
$(function() {
$.fn.addPassClear =
function(text)
{
  return $(this).each(
  function()
  {
    $(this).focus(function(event){$(this).passFocusize(text); $(this).select(); });
    $(this).blur(function(event){$(this).passBlurize(text); });
  });
}
$.fn.passFocusize =
function(text)
{
  return $(this).each(
  function()
  {
    if ($(this).val()==text && $(this).attr("type")=="text")
    {
      $(this).val("");
      this.type="password";
    }
  });
};
$.fn.passBlurize =
function(text)
{
  return $(this).each(
  function()
  {
    if ($(this).val()=="")
    {
      $(this).val(text);
      this.type="text";
    }
  });
};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make the input type="textbox" you'll be able to see the password.

Comment: Ofcourse, but then the password will be visible too. I just need the label to be text.

Comment: im not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: As soon as the box receives focus, change it to a type="password" . Presumably you've already got code that clears out the value when the box is focused, so just add it there.

The plugin route might be better though.

Comment: @WaffleMatt: Great idea, but I'm not sure how to do that, can someone help with the code? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to dynamically overlay an <input type="text"> on top of the password field to do this.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is close to what Dan provided above.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function SwapLabel(id, label, alttype) {
        $(id).focus(function () {
            if (this.value == label) {
                this.value = "";
                if (this.type == 'text' && label == 'Password') {
                    this.type = alttype;
                }
            }
        });
        $(id).blur(function () {
            if (this.value == "") {
                this.value = label;
                if (this.type == alttype && label == 'Password') {
                    this.type = 'text';
                }
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SwapLabel('#UserName', 'Username', '');
        SwapLabel('#Password', 'Password', 'password');
    });
</script>
```

An alternative here would be to omit the "label" parameter, and just use the "title" value, which is basically what labelify.js does. You could add in the part of labelify that just applies these event handlers to all inputs of type text if you wanted. Or download labelify  and add the below code where needed:

```
            if (this.type == 'text' && label == 'Password') {
                this.type = alttype;
            }

            if (this.type == 'text' && label == 'Password') {
                this.type = alttype;
            }
```

The only advantage my snippet has over labelify is that it includes the answer to your original question:

> I wonder if its possible somehow to show "Password" label as text (instead of ••••) inside the password field?